# Swift 3 Error: posix_spawn: error 13 When running Process command

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I am writing a macOS app in Swift 3 that should run the command `/usr/local/jamf/bin/jamf policy -id 20`. I am consistently getting the error `[9188:134113] [General] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13`. I am not sure what is causing this error, my guess is it has something to do with not being able to run the command as root? Here is my code:

```
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/local/jamf/bin"
task.arguments = ["sudo jamf policy -id 20"]

task.launch()
```

This command works fine when used directly in Terminal. Any suggestions or reasons why this is happening will help! Thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same issue by any chance did you figure out a solution for this?